# OpenLayers: I get an error when setting styleMap thru an array

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am loading all my layers by iterating through an array.  In the array there are layers with corresponding styles (ex. `{title : "layer1", style : style_a}, {title : "layer2", style : style_b}`).  `style_a` and `style_b` are predefined in the function.  How can I specify the correct stylemap while loading my layer?  When I try to use my code below I get the following error:

```
"Object style_a has no method 'createSymbolizer'".

var style_a_stylemap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap ({
            'default': new OpenLayers.Style({
                strokeColor: "#6495ed",
                strokeWidth: 3,
                strokeOpacity: 0.8                  
            })                          
        });

var hydrant_stylemap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap ({
            'default': new OpenLayers.Style({
                pointRadius: 3,
                fillColor: "#9de24f",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: "#2da725",
                strokeWidth: 0.5            
            })                          
        });

for (var i in layer_data) {
                var layer_name = layer_data[i].title;
                //alert(layer_name);
                var layer_url = layer_data[i].url;
                //alert(layer_url);
                var layer_style = layer_data[i].style;
                //alert (layer_style);
                layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(layer_name, {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: layer_url,
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                        })
                    }),
                    //styleMap: layer_style,
                    //...load stylemap
                });
                //turn layer off
                layer.styleMap = layer_style;
                layer.setVisibility(false);
                map.addLayer(layer);
            }
```

Comment: In other words, what needs to be in my Json file so that it will recognize my variable above?  Do I need my style array to be encapsulated with curly brackets or regular brackets?

Comment: Can I store a variable object in the json file?